# Trying to figure out how to format what my linq statement returns

Tags: c#, linq

My code below doesn't work and I'm trying to figure out how to get it working. I want to format what the linq statement returns as a string and the method needs to return a list of the formatted strings. How can I make my method work?

```
public List<string> GetCurrencies()
    {
        DataClassesDataContext context = new DataClassesDataContext();

        var result = from c in context.Currencies
                     orderby c.Abbreviation ascending
                     select new { Abbreviation = c.Abbreviation, Description = c.Name };

        return result.Distinct().ToString(result.Abbreviation + " - " + result.Description).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you want: `return result.Distinct().Select(r => r.Abbreviation + " - " + r.Description).ToList();`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
return context.Currencies.OrderBy(x => x.Abbreviation).Distinct().Select(x => string.Format("{0} - {1}",x.Abbreviation,x.Description)).ToList();
```